# GCC template compilation no method checking

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, g++

I have a problem with some code:

```cpp
template<T>
class Ptr{
public:
    Ptr(T* ptr_ = 0) : ptr(ptr_) {}
    Ptr(Ptr const& other) : ptr(other.ptr->clone()) {}
private:
    T* ptr;
};


class Statement{
};


class Test_Statement{
private:
    Ptr<Statement> ptr;
}
```

The thing is: **class Statement** have no method **clone** !
And when i'm compiling code with GCC 4.6, there is no error
But when i'm compiling with Visual Studio 2005 (VC8) there is error that Statement has no clone method.
In fact in copy constructor can look like this:

```
Ptr(Ptr const& other) : ptr(other.ptr->clone()) {
    bla bla
    some random code
    NULL->abcd();
}
```

And there is no error!

So my question is:
1) Why GCC compiler don't even check unused code?
2) Is there some compilation flags or options, so GCC would print error or warning?

**EDIT:

3) Is there a soultion to disable Visual Compiler error on this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is not allowed to issue an error for this code, because nowhere the copy constructor of `Ptr<Statement>` is used.

Unless used somewhere and in need of an instantiation, a compiler is not allowed to instantiate the body of a member function of a class template (the initializer list counts as belonging to the constructor function body). Hence you are allowed to put code into such bodies that is only valid for some, but not all, template arguments. It then depends on the user of the template whether ultimately his program becomes invalid or not.

If you would try to copy a `Test_Statement`, you would notice that you get an error because that would trigger the implicit definition of `Test_Statement`'s copy constructor and then would instantiate `Ptr<Statements>`'s constructor.

Comment: i added a EDIT to original post

Answer (score 1):

> Why GCC compiler don't even check unused code?

Templates are only instantiated when needed; and each member of a class template is regarded as a separate template in this context. So, unless your program attempts to copy-initialise a `Ptr<Statement>`, or otherwise forces instantiation of the copy constructor, it won't be instantiated. If it isn't, then only the basic syntax is checked; it's impossible to tell whether `ptr->clone()` is well-formed without knowing the type of `ptr`.

> Is there some compilation flags or options, so GCC would print error or warning?

Not that I know of, although there are a [lot of flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html), so I might have missed one. If there were such a flag, then it would break a lot of valid code.

> Is there a soultion to disable Visual Compiler error on this?

Perhaps upgrading to one of this decade's compiler versions might help. I get the impression that it's more conformant these days, although I have no direct experience.

Comment: on visual 2008(VC9) this problem also occurs.

Comment: @WaciX: That's a shame. Luckily, there are at least two more recent versions than that - believe it or not, it's 2014 already. Maybe they fixed template instantiation in one of those; or maybe they didn't.

Comment: @WaciX [VS2013 has no problem compiling this program](http://rextester.com/LDTS88425).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that visual 2005,08,10,12,13 works well if you just compile the code with almost no options
I think there is a glitch or specific options or flags in my build environment that can trigger the error.
I remember that cl commands was with this options: /TP /GL /O2 /EHsc /MD but that's not it